# Is there a better way to implement this IEquatable interface with generic types

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Currently I have a class that is pretty much just a wrapper around a Boolean to represent a value from some physical hardware. I will have another class like this which is a double. As the system grows we may have more complex types so I want things to be expandable, but I am starting here. All these classes are representing physical values so they need to be equatable so we can check their validity. I have implemented them this way thus far:

I have an ISignalValue interface which implements `IEquatable<ISignalValue>`

```
    public interface ISignalValue : IEquatable<ISignalValue>
    {
       public string AssociatedSignal { get; set; }
    }
```

I then have a generic base class which implements this interface, and from which every SignalValue will inherit.

```
public class SignalValue<T> : ISignalValue
{
    public readonly T Value;

    public SignalValue(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public string AssociatedSignal { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(ISignalValue other)
    {

        if (Value is IEquatable<T>)
        {
            return Value.Equals((IEquatable<T>)other);
        }
        else return false;
    }   
}
```

Finally, here is a signal value I have implemented.

```
public class DiscreteValue : SignalValue<DiscreteValue>
{
    public DiscreteValue(bool value) : base(value){}

    public double ToDouble() => Value ? 1 : 0;

    public static implicit operator DiscreteValue(bool b) => new DiscreteValue(b);
    public static implicit operator bool(DiscreteValue d) => d.Value;

}
```

I created the implicit operators because I want the user of the class to be able to do things like
`discreteValue.Equals(true)` so they don't need to do things like `discreteValue.Equals(new DiscreteValue(true))`

Now, this is all working fine. But what I'm wondering is, is there a better way to implement this, most specifically, the IEquatable interface? For some reason, defining a DiscreteValue as `DiscreteValue : SignalValue<DiscreteValue>` seems strange. A DiscreteValue is a SignalValue of type DiscreteValue? It feels like using the word in a definition of the word itself.

My initial thought was to define a DiscreteValue as `DiscreteValue: SignalValue<bool>` which makes more sense. But the problem with that is, when I do something like the following it will fail because one is `IEquatable<bool>` and the other is `IEquatable<DiscreteSignal>`.

I get this exception:

> Unable to cast object of type '-omitted-.Values.DiscreteValue' to type
> 'System.IEquatable`1[System.Boolean]'

```
public bool Equals(ISignalValue other)
{

   if (Value is IEquatable<T>)
   {
     return Value.Equals((IEquatable<T>)other);
   }
   else return false;
 }
```

So, is there a better way to deal with this, or is defining a DiscreteValue as `DiscreteValue: SignalValue<DiscreteValue>` the way to go?

Comment: Side note: there is nothing wrong with using "Curiously Recurring Template Pattern in C#"...

Comment: I think that's more than a side note...that pretty much answers my question!